# Integrate fiddler with Flex technology

Tags: flex3, fiddler, amf

How can I integrate fiddler with Flex 3? Flex uses - AMF protocol to exchange messages.

Can someone please help me in integrating Fiddler with Flex technology?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you mean by "integrate", but Fiddler should see your Flex traffic just fine. A community member has written an Inspector object for the AMF format; he's posted the archive in the Files section of the Fiddler Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler

Answer (score 0):

You can download an inspector plugin for AMF from http://amfparser.codeplex.com/.

Just download the dll, put it into Fiddlers "Inspectors" folder and restart Fiddler. Now you should have a new "AMF" view within the inspectors view.

Comment: Sorry to open up this old thread again—but where in the name of all that is holy do you find this *.dll*? Apparently, this plugin has moved to GitHub, but nowhere in either the archive (of the link you provided) or in the GitHub repository is there a .dll file. Do you happen to know where I can find it, or if there's something I'm missing?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy You are right, it can't be downloaded. I've created an issue for this on Github: https://github.com/ohjeongwook/AMFParser/issues/2
Else, you need to build it on your own :(

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I think, I know how you can get (didn't tried). Go to http://amfparser.codeplex.com/ -> Download the archive -> extract -> locate "releases" -> "4" -> Rename the contained file into "AMFParser.dll". This should be the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Fiddler 4 with amf parser but no success it was showing all garbage data. I found Charles Proxy similar to Fiddler but not that advanced but it has great amf support and i was able to see all the requested response properly.
https://www.charlesproxy.com/